# Затемнение контента при нажатии на копку меню

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Нужно реализовать меню, при нажатии на которое блок, в котором это меню находится, будет затемняться, а оно само должно появиться с анимацией (по-моему, растворение). Ещё кнопка меню должна трансформироваться к крестик.

Подскажите как реализовать данную фишку. Если такая реализация есть в Bootstrap 4, буду благодарен за совет.

Comment: [JonSuh hamburgers](https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers/) вот используйте на здоровье!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<img id="menu" src="../images/" onclick="menu()">
```

JS:

```
function menu(params) {
    var head = document.getElementById("head");
    head.style.transitionProperty = "filter";
    head.style.transitionDuration = "375ms";
    head.style.filter = "brightness(40%)";
}
```